# Where is the documentation for Events of Footable (new version)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, footable

I can't seem to find anywhere on Footable Plugins documentation the events that are fired for footable and how to handle them?

Nothing much about events is given here:-http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html

Where can I find this documentation?

Comment: Seems like the link you provide **IS** the documentation.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is the documentation. But nowhere in the documentation could I find the Footable events like row toggle event. That is the problem.

Comment: Just post it as an "issue" here : https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it myself.

There actually is a documentation for this:-
https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/jsdocs/index.html
https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/jsdocs/FooTable.html

The link was given at the plugin page itself. Just click on JSDocs which is the second last link in the menu.

Was the most unexpected place o find it. It should have been on the left with the remaining important links.

I was just looking for the table expand event. It is "expand.ft.row".

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like the link you provide IS the documentation...
You will have to find by yourself.

Try using this, for your investigation:

```
$("*").on("mouseenter mousedown mouseup click mouseleave",function(e){
    console.log(e.type+"\n"+e.target);
});
```

This console logs every event and event target for all elements.
So if if you can narrow elements too...

Just put the event list you want to test there...
;)